# Apache virtual host for server in local network

Tags: ubuntu, linux-networking

How to create a virtual host in Apache for a server on a local network so that it can be accessed via the Internet. I have server with statick ip and working site on em (first.mysite.org)  , but i want to have access to my another application on server in local network , to give it a domain name (second.mysite.org) and have access from the Internet, and not only from the local network . Its working on the one mashine , first native on server with statick ip ( 10.10.1.10)  , another on same server , but on virtual mashine ip (10.10.1.20). The first site can be accessed both via ip and via domain name, but the second one can only be accessed via its ip